# SSRS open connections issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I've small doubts in SSRS, When we are working with SSRS R2 do we need to close connections explicitly? I believe SSRS it self will handle these connections issue.

If I'm wrong where can we handle in SSRS can  you suggest me? Coz I'm getting problems while working with SSRS like too many connections and too many users connected to server.

Hope you understand.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the database end and do a trace while you are working. That will give you more information on what is going on. i.e. prove that the problem resides with SSRS connecting too often before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

I never configure anywhere to explicitly close the connection. It must be handled by SSRS engine itself. You can turn on the SQL Profiler to find the rootcause ?